# Simulate ORA-3113: end-of-file on communication channel

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have a C# Windows IIS server (Windows Server 2003) application connecting to an Oracle database hosted on Linux (10gR2 on Red Hat 5.3). Intermittetly, Oracle throws an ORA-3113: end-of-file on communication channel error. This screws up the OracleConnection object in C#. Then, any new OracleCommands that try to use the OracleConnection all fail saying the connection has been closed.

I have reviewed the Oracle trace files generated by this error and have isolated the problem to faulty network hardware and am working to fix it.

However, I need to make my C# code more robust and have it respond appropriately to this error by closing and not using that connection object anymore. It is easy to catch the exception in C#, but I cannot reproduce the network issue in the Development environment to prove my code works & cleans up after itself.

```
try
{
  oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(OracleException exception)
{
  if(exception.Code == 3113)
    CloseAndCleanup();
}
```

I have tried coding a PL/SQL trigger on a table that throws an ORA-3113 when I try to INSERT into the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCHEMA.TABLE
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON SCHEMA.TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CONNECTION_LOST_CONTACT   EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (CONNECTION_LOST_CONTACT, -3113);
BEGIN
  RAISE CONNECTION_LOST_CONTACT;
END;
```

This throws the right error, but doesn't corrupt the OracleConnection object in C#. I can still send commands to the OracleConnection and it works.

**How can I accurately simulate the ORA-3113 error?**

Comment: have you tried killing your Oracle session??? (or have your dba do it for you)

Comment: Killing the Oracle session myself (or via a DBA) would result in a clean kill which would not throw an ORA-3113.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ORA-3113` means that a server process/thread that was assigned to a client unexpectedly died or was killed deliberately.
You can produce `ORA-3113` error by manually killing a server process/thread. Killing session wont produce that error.

To reproduce that error you can take following steps:

1) Determine server process/thread associated with your session

```
select p.spid  -- process ID
     , s.program  -- your oracle client
  from v$process p
  join v$session s
    on p.addr = s.paddr
```

On the server side

2) Use `orakill` (windows) or `kill -9 ..` (Linux) to kill server thread/process

Windows example

```
c:\> orakill ORACLE_SID spid
```

After that you will get the `ORA-3113` on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw that exception manually from some PL-SQL code (like in a trigger).

Comment: In my question, I stated that I already tried creating a trigger to throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can *kill* your session.

```sql
alter system kill 'sid,serial#' immediate
```

You can query [V$SESSION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223), or maybe [V$MYSTAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_2071.htm#REFRN30158) and work it out but it's probably better to use [`sys_context`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions184.htm#SQLRF06117) and the `USERENV` namespace.

```
select sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') from dual
```

will get you the current session id (`sid`) and you can then query V$SESSION to get the `serial#`.

This procedure will kill the session that ran it:

```sql
create or replace procedure kill_my_session is

   l_sid v$session.sid%type;
   l_serial v$session.serial#%type;

begin

   select sid, serial#
     into l_sid, l_serial
     from v$session
    where sid = (select sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') from dual)
          ;

   execute immediate 'alter system kill session '''|| l_sid  
                       || ',' || l_serial# || ''' immediate';

end;
```

Of course, you could always just do it manually, which might be easier.

Comment: If I issued the Kill command myself, Oracle would cleanly close the connection & not throw a ORA-3113.

Comment: Yes, it would not throw ORA-3113, but it would kick you off, the database, which _almost_ amounts to the same thing. However, if you then ran the procedure over a DB link then you might (I'm not near a DB and can't test so don't want to say for certain) get the error you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I know the initial question was targeting system setup with Oracle on Linux. For others out there running the Oracle database XE on **Windows** there is an easy way to reproduce this.

Go into the running Services (found in Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools) and simply stop the process named **OracleServiceXE**. This will also cause ORA-03113 to appear.